Toggle Caps Lock with the Shift key while keeping Shift key's normal functionality
I want to use the Caps Lock key on my Windows laptop for something else entirely.
How can I set the Shift key to toggle Caps Lock on a single press, while keeping its regular functionality when it's pressed as part of a combo or long-pressed?
It's possible to set the Shift key to toggle off Caps Lock, but I'd like for it to also toggle it on.


On what system? Under what circumstances?

The OS and likely the system hardware will be relevant, necessary even, in order to answer this question. Please EDIT your post to give us all the information we will need in order to answer you.
